# Is there any quick way to deactivate the 2 player feature?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

Yesterday, I activated the 2 player feature, just to see what the second player could do.

Thing is, I never figured out an in-game way to deactivate it. I ended up closing the application and starting it back up again to remove the second player.

Is there any quicker way than resetting the entire game? Something that can be done in-game to remove the 2nd player?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The second player can leave the game at any time by shaking their half of the controller, the same way they join in.

Comment: Oh, I thought they joined in when they pressed A. Should try it out.

Comment: That mechanism seems ripe for accidental disconnects...

Comment: @jpmc26 Accidental disconnecting is exactly how I discovered it.  Not sure if you can disconnect in a battle though.

Comment: @Nathan You cannot.